# Removing path from a zip file using python

Tags: python, path, unzip

I have a zip file that has a path.  When I unzip the file using python and put it in my target folder, it then creates all of the files in the path inside my target folder.

Target: d:\unzip_files
zip file has a path and file name of: \NIS\TEST\Files\tnt.png

What happens: d:\unzip_files\NIS\TEST\Files\tnt.png

Is there a way to hae it just unzip the tnt.png file into d:\unzip_files?  Or will I have to read down the list and move the file and then delete all of the empty folders?

```
import os, sys, zipfile

zippath = r"D:\zip_files\test.zip"
zipdir = r"D:\unzip_files"

zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zippath, "r")
for name in zfile.namelist():
    zfile.extract(name, zipdir)
zfile.close()
```

So, this is what worked..

```
import os, sys, zipfile

zippath = r"D:\zip_files\test.zip"
zipdir = r"D:\unzip_files"

zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zippath, "r")
for name in zfile.namelist():
    fname = os.path.join(zipdir, os.path.basename(name))
    fout = open(fname, "wb")
    fout.write(zfile.read(name))

fout.close()
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

How about reading file as binary and dump it?  Need to deal cases where there is pre-existing file.

```
for name in zfile.namelist():

    fname = os.path.join(zipdir, os.path.basename(name))
    fout = open(fname, 'wb')
    fout.write(zfile.read(name))
```

Comment: OK worked great kind of. With one item in the zip it didn't work(name but no data) with 2 items it did the first one fine, but the second has a file name, but nothing in it. So it reads the last one and creats the name but doesn't put the data in it. Then realized I had forgotten to change my .close to "fout.close().  I put the fixed code in the origional post.

Comment: didn't realize .close() was necessary.  Glad to know that it worked for ya.